# How to use .d.ts files

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, typescript

I have a project that I am using typescript in and want to use typescript definition files to interface with libraries such as mongoose. I have installed the appropriate .d.ts files via

```
tsd query mongoose --action install
tsd query node --action install
```

I'm trying to import mongoose via the following code

```
///<reference path="../typings/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts">
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

class MongooseUser
{
    constructor()
    {

    }

    useMongoose():any {
        return mongoose.Collection;
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm not trying to do anything here at the moment, but when I transpile this I get the following errors

```
Unable to resolve external module '"mongoose"'.
Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'mongoose'.
```

Either looking for a complete example on how to use these things (which sadly the docs are terrible at providing) or some pointers.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: No I'm using PHPStorm

Comment: I was a bit inexperienced with these but the solution was to simply provide the correct path to the .d.ts files. At the time I didn't understand that they are just interfaces that allow you to type the objects and have nothing to do with the actual mongoose file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reference tag is incorrect. You forgot to close it `/>`. Fixed:

```
///<reference path="../typings/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts"/>
```

This will help you prevent such mistakes : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#references

Comment: I'm using gulp rather than grunt, but this didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

the d.ts is your definition file it has nothing to do with mongoose package it is only for intellisense, are you sure that mongoose is installed in your node_module please check and install it locally as well as globally